# How can i fix this higher order function code in haskell?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

I want to fix this code

```
h :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
h f = foldr (\x y -> f x : y) []
```

if i put `h (+100) [1,2,3,4,5]` in GHCI

it returns to me `[101,202,303,404,505]`

when i put h `(*10) [1,2,3,4,5]` then

i want to get `[10,200,3000,40000,500000]` list

can anyone help me fixing this code?

Answer (score 4):

You here implemented a `map`, but in order to repeat the same operation multiple times, you need to perform a mapping on the tail `y`:

```
h :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
h f = foldr (\x y -> f x : map f y) []
```

Comment: thank you for helping me to solve this problem.

Comment: i try to mapping in tail that you told me but it occurs error

Comment: How exactly an error occurs when the solution is already in the answer?

Comment: please look around my code in replit https://replit.com/@sangwoo98/PL2021hw2

Comment: @강상우: this will only work for `a -> a`, since the output is reused as input in the next iteration.

Comment: Oh.. thank u for solving this problem i recognize what i missed! I follow you and pulling for you!!

Comment: That will be very very slow when the list is long! That's inherent to the problem though, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Solving the general problem, as [Willem Van Onsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66854359/1477667) does, requires `O(n^2)` time to calculate the first `n` elements, because the function has to be applied `k` times to calculate the `k`th element.

To solve this sort of problem *efficiently*, you will need to take advantage of some additional structure. Based on your examples, I think the most obvious approach is to think about [*semigroup actions*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup_action). That is, instead of applying an *arbitrary function* repeatedly, look for an efficient way to represent the compositions of the function. For example, `(*x)` can be represented by `x`, allowing `(*x) . (*y)` to be represented by `x*y`.

To apply this idea, we first need to transform Willem's solution to make the compositions explicit.

```
h :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
h f0 as0 = go as0 f0
  where
    go [] _ = []
    go (a:as) f = f a : go as (f0 . f)
```

If we like, we can write that as a fold:

```
h :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
h f0 as = foldr go stop as f0
  where
    stop _ = []
    go a r f = f a : r (f0 . f)
```

Now we've structured the function using an accumulator (which is a function). As we compose onto the accumulator, it will get slower and slower to apply it. We want to replace that accumulator with one we can "apply" quickly.

```
{-# language BangPatterns #-}
import Data.Semigroup

repeatedly :: Semigroup s => (s -> a -> a) -> s -> [a] -> [a]
repeatedly act s0 as = foldr go stop as s0
  where
    stop _ = []
    go a r !s = act s a : r (s0 <> s)
```

Now you can use, for example,

```
repeatedly (\(Product s) -> (s*)) (Product 10) [1..5]
==> [10,200,3000,40000,500000]

repeatedly (\(Sum s) -> (s+)) (Sum 100) [1..5]
==> [101,202,303,404,505]
```

In each of these, you accumulate a product/sum which is added to/multiplied by the current list element.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I solved this with Willem Van Onsem's answer. I didn't consider time complexity in my code. Now, I can consider my time complexity with your answer. You are the best coder ever I seen!!!

Comment: @강상우, thanks for the praise, but I don't think it's deserved. I've updated my answer to (hopefully) explain a little more clearly.